# MySQL changed to Windows 2012 and application throws error in datetime field

Tags: java, mysql, windows-server-2012

Our company switched from old AIX box environment to Windows Environment this weekend. The MySQL database was moved from AIX to Windows 2012 servers.

The application are throwing up errors on date fields for any insert statement. MySQL version on Windows is 5.1.56.

Is there any database level datetime setting that has to be  changed in Windows environment? Any drivers to be installed? The application is on Java and may need lot of time changing the code.

Comment: Whats the error, or should we guess?

Comment: Anywhere , where the application containg a datetime field , we get "Incorrect datetime value", if there in null

Comment: after the migration this weekend we are no longer able to send null values to date fields.

Comment: Can you migrate back to the AIX box? Did you do a dry run on Windows prior to the real migration?

Comment: Have `NOT NULL` constraints been added in the new server where previously they were not applied on the old one?

Comment: We have empty string '' being sent from the java application.The mySQl on AIX took the default value set up for the field, in the table.But now on windows, When the empty string is being sent, MySQL throws an error saying " Incorrect datetime value: ''  ".So we don't want to write code to modify for each datetime field in java.Is there any way we can do it at database level to accept or convert the empty strings to valid date.Also switching back to AIX box is the last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the previous MySQL version (on AIX), below is a link to configuring MySQL "SQL-mode" to "emulate" some specific behaviors in MySQL. (The documentation link is for MySQL 5.5, but the date-related options could be the same for MySQL 5.1.) Might even suggesting looking at the configuration file on the previous version of MySQL to see if a "SQL-mode" might had been configured. SQL-mode can also set MYSQL to emulate previous versions of MySQL.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html

Reading from the comments, using a NULL (or empty) string in the place of a date/timestamp field should be corrected in the Java code, but perhaps configuring the "SQL-mode" could mitigate your problem in the short run.

Comment: Thank you. But the team decided to revert back to AIX box, untill completely tested.Will keep this link in mind for future use.Thank you againfor the research